# NoSuchMethodError . The method getPosts was called on null

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to flutter. I am trying to use chopper library and got the error while calling the method.

```
    FutureBuilder<Response> _buildBody(BuildContext context){
    return FutureBuilder<Response>(
      future: Provider.of<PostApiService>(context).getPosts(),
            builder: (context,snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
            final List posts= json.decode(snapshot.data.bodyString);
            return _buildPosts(context,posts);

        }else{
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `Provider` in `didChangeDependencies`.

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _bloc = Provider.of<BlocClass>(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

And change future to

```
 future: _bloc.getPosts(),
```

Make sure define `getPosts()` inside bloc class.